# Having trouble getting Xcode app to compile

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, app-store, xcodebuild

I have the following error when I am building my app

I keep getting the same message again and again. Not sure what to do now.

```
Check dependencies
Internal error occurred while creating dependency graph: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-931/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/Target.subproj/XCCodeSignContext.m:1237
Details:  Error: failed to locate ResourceRules.plist in '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/ResourceRules.plist' or '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/ResourceRules.plist'
Object:   <XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext>
Method:   +defineCodeSignAuxiliaryFilesInTargetBuildContext:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x403d5dfc0>{name = (null), num = 15}
Backtrace:
  0  0x00000001137a39ac -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DevToolsCore)
  1  0x000000010f6546a4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000011387c80a +[XCCodeSignContext defineCodeSignAuxiliaryFilesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  3  0x00000001137f4c10 -[XCProductTypeSpecification computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  4  0x0000000113884a42 -[XCNativeTargetDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5  0x000000011379326d -[PBXTargetBuildContext createDependencyGraphWithTargetDGSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x00000001137a4a2e -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) dg_setTargetSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x00007fff9700120c __invoking___ (in CoreFoundation)
  8  0x00007fff970010a4 -[NSInvocation invoke] (in CoreFoundation)
  9  0x00000001137a3df1 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) processDependencyGraphEvents] (in DevToolsCore)
 10  0x00007fff9700120c __invoking___ (in CoreFoundation)
 11  0x00007fff970010a4 -[NSInvocation invoke] (in CoreFoundation)
 12  0x00000001137ed296 -[XCInvocationQueue _processNextInvocationInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 13  0x00000001137ed6a0 -[XCInvocationQueue _processInvocationsInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 14  0x00007fff919f37fe -[NSThread main] (in Foundation)
 15  0x00007fff919f3776 __NSThread__main__ (in Foundation)
 16  0x00007fff965958bf _pthread_start (in libsystem_c.dylib)
 17  0x00007fff96598b75 thread_start (in libsystem_c.dylib)

(null)
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9700f286 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8de79d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff970994c9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010f6546a4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 110
    4   DevToolsCore                        0x000000011387c80a +[XCCodeSignContext defineCodeSignAuxiliaryFilesInTargetBuildContext:] + 2120
    5   DevToolsCore                        0x00000001137f4c10 -[XCProductTypeSpecification computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] + 656
    6   DevToolsCore                        0x0000000113884a42 -[XCNativeTargetDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] + 3744
    7   DevToolsCore                        0x000000011379326d -[PBXTargetBuildContext createDependencyGraphWithTargetDGSnapshot:] + 4889
    8   DevToolsCore                        0x00000001137a4a2e -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) dg_setTargetSnapshot:] + 460
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9700120c __invoking___ + 140
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff970010a4 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 132
    11  DevToolsCore                        0x00000001137a3df1 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) processDependencyGraphEvents] + 594
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9700120c __invoking___ + 140
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff970010a4 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 132
    14  DevToolsCore                        0x00000001137ed296 -[XCInvocationQueue _processNextInvocationInThreadSlotNumber:] + 388
    15  DevToolsCore                        0x00000001137ed6a0 -[XCInvocationQueue _processInvocationsInThreadSlotNumber:] + 510
    16  Foundation                          0x00007fff919f37fe -[NSThread main] + 68
    17  Foundation                          0x00007fff919f3776 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
    18  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff965958bf _pthread_start + 335
    19  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff96598b75 thread_start + 13
)
```

Comment: is the app called "ResourceRules"?

Comment: don't be silly. ResourceRules is the ceritificate file for iOS/Mac OS X apps...

Comment: Well then, where did the plist go?  Do any of your projects build?

Comment: In your build settings is your app set to build using the iOS 4.0 SDK? If you recently upgraded your Xcode, the 4.0 SDK and simulator isn't included any more, so maybe you need to change your target to 5.0 instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the files were missing. I reinstalled Xcode from the AppStore and it started working again.

I have no idea how the files were missing.